# How many diagonal matrices such that $A^k=I_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How many diagonal matrices $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ are there, such that $A^k=I_n$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$?

Edit: I was thinking about $k$-th roots of 1 on the diagonal and then the answer would probably be $\infty$. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose the diagonal elements are $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$. The determinant of $A$ is $a_1a_2\dotsm a_n$. So the determinant of $A^k$ is $a_1^ka_2^k\dotsm a_n^k$. But the determinant of $I$ is $1$, so $a_1^ka_2^k\dotsm a_n^k=1$.

Comment: And we can go even stronger than that: $a^k = 1$ for all $k$, since (if we denote by $D(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ the diagonal matrix with diagonal values $b_1,\ldots,b_n$), $D(a_1,\ldots,a_n)^k = D(a_1^k,\ldots,a_n^k) = I_n = D(1,\ldots,1)$.